# Application error while deploying on heroku

Tags: python, django, web-deployment, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

I'm following django for beginners by william vincent and i followed every step carefully and in the end while deploying my pages app on heroku, i see this application error. Please guide me, I'm a beginner in programming.

here in the image you can see application error

[![here in the image you can see application error][1]][1]

1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VBoX.jpg!This is log showing on heroku...I have installed django and it's showing module not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asIUk.jpg)

Comment: This is my log..... i have installed django but here it's showing no module named django....

Answer (score 0):

"Application Error" or similar is always caused by your own application code. Routing errors will normally only surface themselves within the logs of your application.
To track this kind of issue down you should look at your logs:

```
$ heroku logs --tail --app your_app_name
```

or log in to your heroku dashboard and click on your `app` and at the top right corner click on `More` option and than click on `View logs` and check the logs that will help you to figure your mistake
[image: Demo Image]

Comment: Thanks ankit for your guidance.... i solved it through logs.....I have been yoga teacher before programming...if you need any help, you can ask me.....

Comment: Thank You, If i need to ask me i will definitely ask